# Parse.com simple query: login and display account balance

Tags: javascript, authentication, parse-platform

I was recently at a hackathon and saw quite a few people using Parse, so I decided to check it out and read some guides online. Can someone take a look at my code? I followed Parse documentation so it should be fairly readable. I'm trying to get the balance for the user when they log in and display it.

```
Parse.User.logIn("user", "pass", {
  success: function(user) {
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        results[0].save({ key: value }, {
          success: function(result) {

            var arr = result.balances;
            var balance = sumArray(arr);
            var charge = result.charge;

            if(balance < charge)
                document.write("Insufficient funds. Must have " + balance + charge + " balance left");
            else if(balance == charge)
                document.write("Oops!");
                document.write("Sorry, balance cannot reach zero");

            var mssg = "";
            var today = formatDate(new Date());

            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                mssg += arr[i] + " ,";
            }
            document.write(today - 1 + 1);
            document.write(mssg);

          },
          error: function(result, error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});


function sumArray(arr) {
    var S = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        S += arr[i];
    }
    return S;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: '400px',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#form").datepicker({
            maxDate: '-18y'
        });
        $("#form").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });
    })
});


function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    var day = '' + d.getDate();

    return day;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Promises**

Promises are the next big thing in JavaScript. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Luckily, Parse supports Promises and you should make good use of them.
Essentially, Promises will replace the messy callback pyramid structure you have here

```
Parse.User.logIn("user", "pass", {
  success: function(user) {
    ...
      success: function(results) {
        ...
          success: function(result) {
            ...
          },
          error: function(result, error) {
            // error
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // error
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // error
  }
});
```

Promises use the `then` function, which can be given callbacks to be called when the promise is fulfilled or has failed. Promises can also propogate errors, not calling any callbacks until an error handler is encountered. So, your code can be re-written as:

```
Parse.User.logIn("user", "pass").then(function(user) {
  return query.find();
}).then(function(results) {
  // ...
}).then(function(result) {
  // ...
}, function(error) {
  // error
});
```

One thing to remember that a successful promise **does not** imply the Parse Query itself was successful. A successful promise simply means your query was successfully executed, regardless of what value was returned by the query. So, make sure to check the return value from Parse:

```
.then(function(result)){   // Promise succeeded
  if(!result){             // check if return is not null
    // do something
  }
})
```

**Duplicated event handling**

You have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

and then you also have this

```
$(function () {
```

Why? Just put all the content inside the `.ready` function and you are good to go

**Beware of Javascript string concatenation**

This is one of the most naive mistakes:

```
document.write("Insufficient funds. Must have " + balance + charge + " balance left");
```

Let's assume balance=10 and charge=20. You expect it to print :

`Insufficient funds. Must have 30 balance left`

What it will actually print is:

`Insufficient funds. Must have 1020 balance left`

String concatenation in javascript is not well-defined when types get mixed. In your case string + int types are getting mixed. What you need to do instead is:

```
document.write("Insufficient funds. Must have " + (balance + charge) + " balance left");
```

Notice the parantheses besides the int types.

**Mixing logic and view**

You are mixing your logic. Look here

```
document.write(mssg);
```

Code that is rendering the view such as `document.write` should be handled in a separate function. It becomes very messy and hard to debug when you combine your logic-side and view-side code in one place. Read up on MVC (Model-View-Controller).

**Illusion of binding**

Take a look here why dropping brackets and misleading indentation can have unforeseen consequences

```
if(balance < charge)
  document.write("Insufficient funds. Must have " + b + ch + " balance left");
else if(balance  == charge)
  document.write("Oops!");
  document.write("Sorry, balance cannot reach zero");
```

At what times do you think *"Sorry, balance cannot reach zero"* message will be printed? Will it be printed only when `balance == charge`? Unfortunately, no! It will be printed **every single time!**

Why? Because your indentation leads to you believe that the 2nd `document.write` statement is bound to the `else` clause, when infact it isn't. Dropping brackets might make code look more clean & readable, but make sure you don't let the indentation give you false illusion of binding.

**Avoid unnecessary string creation**

In Javascript, strings are immutable. When you do something like this

```
var mssg = "";
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    mssg += arr[i] + " ,";
}
```

it isn't "modifying" the `mssg` string, but instead creating a new string on every iteration. For large iterations, say a million, you will definitely have a performance hit. Other languages like C# solve this problem by using a StringBuilder class, but for Javascript you can use the `join()` method instead

```
var mssg = arr.join(", ");
```

**Incorrect code**

```
document.write(today - 1 + 1);
```

Why are you doing this? What is the purpose of `-1 + 1`?
To me, it seems like you are trying to convert the date to an `int`. But you wouldn't need to do that if you hadn't done this earlier

```
var day = '' + d.getDate();
```

Don't add the empty string to the date in the first place. Just leave it as this

```
var day = d.getDate();
```

**Underscore.js**

Naive summation operations such as

```
function sumArray(arr) {
    var S = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; a++){
        S += arr[i];
    }
    return S;
}
```

can be replaced by powerful helper functions provided by the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library. Using `reduce()` function, we can re-write it as follows:

```
// return sum of all elements of an array
var sum = _.reduce(arr, function(memo, num){ return memo+ num; }, 0);
return sum;
```

**Lacking comments**

Please always comment your code.